# Joomla Extension Manager - Install page is blank after upgrade from 2.5 to 3

Tags: php, joomla

as described in the title after upgrading Joomla, when I go into **Extensions - Manage - Install** the page comes up with no options to upload, in fact the page is just blank with only the 'help' and 'options' buttons up on the top right.

[Blank Extensions - install page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/racBn.jpg)

Obviously this means I can't download any extensions.

I originally upgraded from 2.5.8 to 2.5.28 with no problem, then following the suggested upgrade path I went from 2.5.28 to 3.5.1, still no problem. 
It was when I upgraded from 3.5.1 to 3.6.5 that I lost the ability to display the Install page, and thinking it was just an anomaly I upgraded to 3.8.3 where, unfortunately it still seems to be a problem.

Any ideas would be gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: Can you send the link of this "following the suggested upgrade path I went from 2.5.28 to 3.5.1". I want to check if all the steps are mentioned.

Comment: Hi, the link is: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration**"Going to Joomla! 3.x

Joomla! 2.5.28 can only be migrated to the latest Joomla 3.x in two steps. First migrate to version 3.5.1"**

Comment: I did go this route, then Joomla update offered 3.6.5, which is where the problem first came up, then Joomla update offered 3.8.3 - I upgraded again but the problem is still there.

Comment: The procedure seems to be correct. I recommend you to check this link which tells about the requirements for Joomla 3X. https://docs.joomla.org/Technical_requirements

Comment: Thanks for that. I've decided to roll back using a manual backup made with cPanel to v3.5.1, which was the last version where the install section was working and then upgrade again from there.

Comment: If you see my other comment , you'll see that I've narrowed it down to it being a Firefox issue as it worked in both Edge and Chrome. I prefer to use IceDragon for security/privacy reasons... Not sure where to look now, though.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED** - Hope this might help anyone else that comes across this problem.

I was flummoxed at first but when I tried to open the page in two alternative browsers (**Edge** and **Chrome**) rather than my preferred **IceDragon** and it seemed to be displaying with no problem, I realised it must either be to do with a **Firefox add-on** or one of the many tweaks I had previously made to FireFox's **about:config**.

I tried restarting IceDragon with no add-ons but there was no change.

So, up next was the laborious task of comparing my probably over-paranoid **about:config** settings with the **default settings**. 
Turns out, it was the **dom.storage.enabled** setting, which I'd set to **false**. When I set it back to **true**, all was fine... Hooray!

One problem with **FireFox** and it's derivatives is that although you can easily change cookie settings and make exceptions etc, that doesn't deal with local storage. You can switch it off in **about:config** with **dom.storage.enabled** but that's only on or off (with no exceptions)

I am now using an add-on called **Cookie Controller** instead, to disable **DOM Storage** but still be able to whitelist trusted sites.

Glad I worked it out in the end... Thought I was going mad!

Thanks to everyone for their patience!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Joomla cache and also the web browser cache may help with displaying the new pages correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already cleared both Joomla and browser caches. I've rolled back using a manual backup made with cPanel to v3.5.1, which was the last version where the install section was working. About to try to upgrade now. Would I be able to jump now straight to 3.8.4?

Comment: No, the upgrade process from 3.5.1 takes you to 3.6.5 and then probably to 3.8.4. For some hints, see: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18953/120

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a good check through and see if it helps.

Comment: I've been through and followed the checklist and as soon as I got to 3.6.5 the problem started again. But, this time I have a bit more info - It seems to be a firefox problem as I opened the page on both Edge and Chrome and it's displayed as it should be. So I then tried Firefox with add-ons disabled but that didn't work either. I use the Comodo Icedragon flavour of Firefox (v52.0.0.4 (32-bit)), so I don't know if it's maybe some security setting from Comodo or possibly something I may have set in the past in about:config...